# What phoneset to use for Arabic for cmusphinx model

Tags: android, pocketsphinx

Can I use the following in db.phone to build Arabic model to be used in Android: (file content is too big and unformatted so couldn't paste it here as a code or quote)

[link to file contain content I think it can be used as db.phone](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2AP3P_CLPSFYjFLVjVBaWRvckk)

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Linux-Distribution) in build. I am following [this tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialam/) to build my own model to recognize some words (500-1500). I have prepared some files to build similar to the following files:

```
> your_db.dic - Phonetic dictionary, your_db.phone - Phone set file,
> your_db.lm.DMP - Language model, your_db.filler - List of fillers,
> your_db_train.fileids - List of files for training,
> your_db_train.transcription - Transcription for training,
> your_db_test.fileids - List of files for testing,
> your_db_test.transcription - Transcription for testing.
```

I am not Pocketsphinx expert. Can anyone help?

Comment: When adding code, make sure there are 4 blanks before each line. You can also mark all lines in the text box and press Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0):

Phoneset should contain english letters, for example:

```
 مرحبا m r H b 'a a
```